# Script Optimization

Tags: tcl, wsh

I have some questions:

1. How to support for quotes; set data "("C:\text.txt", True)".
2. Please revise the below code for optimization process and faster.
3. How to hold or pause until the txt file was created before continue or read this file.

```
set A_mark   {"}
set B_mark   {(}
set C_mark   {)}
set D_mark   {,}
set path     [pwd]
set pathFile [file join $path text.txt]
set strgdt   [join [list "Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile" "$B_mark$A_mark$pathFile$A_mark$D_mark True$C_mark"] ""]

#HERE THE FIRST QUESTIONS
#I would like to write the format string example like this: Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\text.txt", True)

set vbs [list \
        {On Error Resume Next} \
        {Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10} \
        {Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &h20} \
        {Dim objFSO, objFile} \
        {Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")} \
        "$strgdt" \ ;#The variable from above
        #so on..
        ]

#Write the vbsFile
set oFile [open "vscr.vbs" w]

#Run the vbs file then create a txt file
set res [exec {cmd.exe /c [file join $path vbscrpting.vbs]}]

#HERE THE SECOND QUESTIONS
#How to make sure the file already created and if the txt file still on processing then wait until finish create it.

#Open txt file
set txtFile [open "text.txt" r]
```

Answer (score 0):

As to the first question, just use templating:

```
set script [format {
    On Error Resume Next
    Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
    Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &h20
    Dim objFSO, objFile
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("%s", True)
    # So on
} $pathFile]
```

Then you need to actually *write* your script to the script file.
You're opening the script file but do not write anything to it.
Do something like:

```
set sfname [file join $path myscript.vbs]
set fd [open $sfname w]
puts $fd $script
close $fd
```

Then call the interpreter on it.
There's no sense to go the long way—as you did—by round-tripping
through `cmd.exe` which would eventually call into `ShelleExecuteEx()`
Win32 API call to figure out how to process a `.vbs` file,—just
call the interpterer:

```
set res [exec [list cscript.exe /nologo $sfname]]
```

By the time `exec` finishes, it means the WSH interpreter finished as well,
and so the text file it was supposed to (re)write, is created—*unless*
the interpreter detected an error running any command in the script supplied
to it before the call to `objFSO.CreateTextFile()`, or while processing
that call.

So you need to actually see how your `exec` call performed
by doing something like

```
set rc [catch [list exec [list cscript.exe /nologo $sfname]] out]
if {$rc != 0} {
  puts stderr "WSH script failed: $out"
  exit 42
}
```

I suggest you to refer to the
[`catch` manual](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/catch.htm)
and [`exec` manual](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm#M27).

I would also consider removing the target file for the WSH script to
handle before executing it—either from your Tcl script or from
the WSH script—to be a good practice.
Be sure you're prepared for the case of that file not existing when
you're dealing with this.

---

Note that I suppose the problem which led to you asking your second question
probably has to do with you not writing the script to the script file
so that it ends up being empty and consequently a WSH interpreter called
on it doing nothing and quitting right away.

One side note is that I expicitly called `cscript.exe` which is a command-line WSH interpreter. A bonus point of using it is that if it detects
and error, it writes it to its standard error stream before exiting,
and `exec` reads that data and returns it to your script.
The downside is that executing `cscript.exe` pops a console window up—
unless your Tcl script is run by `tclsh` and is hence already hosted by
a console process.

You may use `wscript.exe` instead of `cscript.exe`: it's a "windowed" version
of a WSH interpreter. It does not pops up a console window but in return
it displays any errors it detects using a silly GUI window, in which someone must click the "OK" button to let the interpreter die. which is very silly
for non-interactive stuff.

`wscript.exe` is run by default when you "just execute" WSH scripts.

So take your pick.